# Search a file in a directory

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I work in a project and I need to know if a file is unique in a directory or not.
So how can I find if a file exists in a directory or not? 
I have the file name without extension and the path of the directory.

Comment: What do you mean by "unique"? And why without extension? Do you mean you want to know whether there are files that differ only in their extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no ready-made function for this I think, but you can use something like this:

```
static bool fileExists( const char *path )
{
    const DWORD attr = ::GetFileAttributesA( path );
    return attr != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES &&
           ( ( attr & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE ) || ( attr & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL ) );
}
```

This verifies that it's a "normal" file. You might want to add/remove flag checks if you want to deal with hidden files, too.

Comment: thank you this is exactely what i need, but i need to know just one thing the parameter (path = directory+filename+extension)?

Comment: @nidahl: Right; the `path` argument is the actual path in the file system.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to do this on a C++ way, but you mentioned a Visual-C++ tag, so there's a way to do it on Visual-C++.NET:

```
using <mscorlib.dll>
using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;

bool search(String folderPath, String fileName) {
    String* files[] = Directory::GetFiles(folderPath, fileName+".*"); //search the file with the name fileName with any extension (remember, * is a wildcard)
    if(files->getLength() > 0)
        return true; //there are one or more files with this name in this folder
    else
        return false; //there arent any file with this name in this folder

}
```